# How to iterate through a CSV file with data organized by columns to make separate arrayLists of each column?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, iterator

I have an Excel file that I converted to a CSV and need to create an `ArrayList` of each column of data. I don't want to manually add each data point. Is there a way to use an iterator to only read in one column at a time and then save that as an `ArrayList`?

I made a method that can read in the whole CSV and save it as an `ArrayList` using a Scanner.

The CSV file is called "Mineral Database NA.csv". An example of a column of data I am trying to isolate has the title "mineralNames", no mineral name is repeated, each name is a string, the delimiter is a comma.

```
private static final File file = new File("../input/Mineral Database NA Final.csv");
private ArrayList<String> dataList;

public IterList() 
{
    dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/** Reads file and adds info to dataList row by row.
*/
public void readFile() throws IOException {
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);

    while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
        String line = fileReader.nextLine();
        dataList.add(line);
    }
}
```

I expect an `ArrayList` of strings that belong to a particular column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of a specific column by splitting the String you receive from your `nextLine()` operation.

Once your `line` field is split into tokens, you can use the index of the specific column you're after and add only that token to the `ArrayList`.

So, picking up from where you set `line`:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
// Now, token 0 corresponds with the first column from the left
// token 1 corresponds with the second column from the left, etc.

// Let's assume then, you want the third column

dataList.add(tokens[2];
```

Adding that code to your `while` loop should get you what you want after you make your `dataList` object available to your `readFile` method.

The one caveat here is that you need to be sure that your CSV file is regular, with each column represented on each line, or else you're going to have to come up with code that deals with out of bound indices.